# Simple aggregating query on indexed table with 14M rows taking long

Tags: mariadb, query-optimization

I'm having trouble running a simple aggregating query on a relatively large table (~14M rows). The query in question `SELECT stageID, SUM(time) as totalTime FROM <table> GROUP BY stageID`
results in 4052 rows and takes ~7 seconds. Running mysql from 11.0.2-MariaDB, client 15.2 for Win64 (AMD64) on a local machine with 16GB RAM, an i7 chip. The data is on an SSD drive so I don't understand the amount of time it takes to send the data..

Using `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...`:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | <table> | index | NULL | uniquekey | 8 | NULL | 13744857 | 100.00 | NULL |

Using `EXPLAIN <table`>:

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stageID | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| playerID | int(11) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| time | int(11) | NO |  | 0 |  |

Included indices:
`UNIQUE KEY (stageID, playerID) FOREIGN KEY (stageID) FOREIGN KEY (playerID)`

`ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci`

Here's the profile of that query:

| Status | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| Starting | 0.000050 |
| checking permissions | 0.000005 |
| Opening tables | 0.000013 |
| After opening tables | 0.000003 |
| System lock | 0.000005 |
| table lock | 0.000005 |
| init | 0.000017 |
| Optimizing | 0.000007 |
| Statistics | 0.000021 |
| Preparing | 0.000015 |
| Sorting result | 0.000007 |
| Executing | 0.000002 |
| Sending data | 6.893190 |
| End of update loop | 0.000010 |
| Query end | 0.000003 |
| Commit | 0.000004 |
| closing tables | 0.000003 |
| Unlocking tables | 0.000002 |
| closing tables | 0.000007 |
| Starting cleanup | 0.000002 |
| Freeing items | 0.000003 |
| Updating status | 0.000039 |
| Reset for next command | 0.000004 |

Upgrading the resources available to MariaDB by using the my-huge.ini config files etc., no changes in execution time.

Comment: If you don't mind about the order, you could skip that with `ORDER BY null`.  I'm not sure, but it might shave a tiny bit off the execution time

Comment: An index on `(stageID, time)` might speed things up. But you're still processing all of the data. Are you looking to achieve a specific execution time for the query (if so, what?), just curious about where the time is being spent, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

The "Sending data" line in your profile output proves that almost all of the 7 seconds is spent copying rows of data between the storage engine layer and the SQL layer.

The EXPLAIN for your query shows an estimate of examining 13744857 rows, and there's no amount of indexes or resources that can change that.

The only ways to speed up this query are:

- Reduce the examined rows by using an indexed condition in the WHERE clause. But that would be a different query. I assume you need the query to sum all the rows for all stageIds.
- Reduce the stored rows in this table by deleting or archiving some.
- Use a summary table to record the sums and keep them updated as rows change in your primary table. It may still take 7 seconds to update the summary table, but you don't have to recalculate the sums every time you read them.
- Get a faster computer.